# Does the prize in cereal violate the non edible restriction in foods?

Tags: united-states, fda, food

In the US the FDA has a regulation that bans toys or trinkets embedded in candy.

This let to banning the [Kinder Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinder_Surprise) egg in the US

Does this regulation also cover the prises in cereal?

If not, what regulates those choking hazards?

Comment: Toys in cereal boxes are in plastic wrappers which would be difficult to ingest, even for a toddler. They are not within the actual cereal.

Comment: @mkennedy but the prise inside the Surprise egg is contained in a large yellow plastic container that's also difficult to ingest.